# Formula for computing rational approximations to square roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation, radicals

I have been playing around with rational approximations to square roots. I am familiar with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots but did not see it there.

I also did not see the formula on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Series_and_product .

I ended up with this formulation and I wondered whether it was known.
\begin{align}
\sqrt{a} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{i=0, i \textrm{ even}}^n {n \choose i} x^{n-i} a^{i/2}}{\sum_{i=0, i \textrm{ odd}}^n {n \choose i} x^{n-i} a^{(i-1)/2}}
\end{align}
for all $x$. In particular, for $x=1$, we have
\begin{align}
\sqrt{a} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{i=0, i \textrm{ even}}^n {n \choose i} a^{i/2}}{\sum_{i=0, i \textrm{ odd}}^n {n \choose i} a^{(i-1)/2}} \; .
\end{align}
The convergence is linear.

I assume this is known but could not find a reference.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Seems kind of like a Padé approximant-ish sort of thing, but I don't recognize those terms. And what's $x$? Does it not matter at all what $x$ is? The first thing is an identity?

Comment: $x$ can be any positive number. Convergence is faster when $x$ is close to $\sqrt{a}$. Yes, the first equation is an identity that does not depend on $x$.

Comment: Note that the fraction inside the limit can be rewritten as $$\sqrt a\dfrac{(x + \sqrt a)^n + (x - \sqrt a)^n}{(x + \sqrt a)^n - (x - \sqrt a)^n}$$ Which makes its convergence to $\sqrt a$ and the properties of that convergence easier to verify.

Comment: Thanks, this makes it much clearer. To add to that, the reason I came to that formula is the following. If we denote $f^n_a(x) = \sqrt{a} \frac{(x+\sqrt{a})^n+(x-\sqrt{a})^n}{(x+\sqrt{a})^n - (x-\sqrt{a})^n}$, then we have:
- $f^1_a(x) = x$
- $f^2_a(x) = \frac{x^2 + a}{2}$, which is the update after one Newton step: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Heron's_method
- $f^n_a(f^p_a(x)) = f^{n+p}_a(x)$

So, effectively, Newton method can be seen as an efficient way of computing $f^n_a(x)$ for large values of $n$ by repeatedly applying $f^2_a$.